# How to round pebble action bar edges?

Tags: pebble-sdk

I'm new to pebble app development and relatively new to programming. I'm trying to create a simple action bar over a text layer. My issue regards its shape. The documentation clearly depicts the action bar as rounded while following its instructions leads to a chunky rectangular vertical rectangle. My question is this: is the vertical rectangle default behavior? If so, can it be changed to the rounded style from within the default api? If not, what steps might I need to take to achieve the rounded (and frankly more attractive) rounded look?

https://developer.pebble.com/docs/c/User_Interface/Layers/ActionBarLayer/#ActionBarLayer

[Nice rounded action bar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRDur.png)

[Ugly rectangular action bar screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vnrn.png)

Answer (score 0):

What SDK are you using? SDK4 or SDK3? The *ugly rectangular action bar* is default for SDK4. See [this](https://github.com/pebble-examples/feature-persist-counter) example. It is made for SDK3, that's why it has rounded bar. If you run it in CloudPebble with SDK4 configuration you will see as expected - 'ugly action bar'

Comment: Ok. That is very insightful actually. I haven't seen information about the change anywhere else. The question remains: aside from running with SDK3, is there any way to style the action bar's shape? I'm looking over the official documentation and there does not seem to be an option. If not I suppose I will have to try something more exotic-- like setting the action bar to clear and designing some very large icons in the shape of action bar pieces with logos embedded.

Comment: @Shadow43375, I'm not sure. Spent an hour looking for an answer. Did not find any ActionBar styling info. I guess, there is no resolution on this, it's just an OS thing.
I guess you just have to be creative and come up with something. Please, if you find solution - share with us.